# Using structured queries to geocode records in a pandas dataframe using GeoPy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, geopy

I would like to use structured queries to do geocoding in GeoPy, and I would like to run this on a large number of observations. I don't know how to do these queries using a pandas dataframe (or something that can be easily transformed to and from a pandas dataframe).

First, some set up:

```
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
Ngeolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")
Ngeocode = RateLimiter(Ngeolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)

df = pandas.DataFrame(["Bob", "Joe", "Ed"])
df["CLEANtown"] = ['Harmony', 'Fargo', '']
df["CLEANcounty"] = ['', '', 'Traill']
df["CLEANstate"] = ['Minnesota', 'North Dakota', 'North Dakota']
df["full"]=['Harmony, Minnesota','Fargo, North Dakota','Traill County, North Dakota']
df.columns = ["name"] + list(df.columns[1:])
```

I know how to run a structured query on a single location by providing a dictionary. I.e.:

```
q={'city':'Harmony', 'county':'', 'state':'Minnesota'}
testN=Ngeocode(q,addressdetails=True)
```

And I know how to geocode from the dataframe simply using a single column populated with strings. I.e.:

```
df['easycode'] = df['full'].apply(lambda x: Ngeocode(x, language='en',addressdetails=True).raw)
```

But how do I turn the columns CLEANtown, CLEANcounty, and CLEANstate into dictionaries row by row, use those dictionaries as structured queries, and put the results back into the pandas dataframe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `apply` method of a DataFrame instead of a Series. This would pass the whole row to the lambda. Example:

```py
df["easycode"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: Ngeocode(
        {
            "city": row["CLEANtown"],
            "county": row["CLEANcounty"],
            "state": row["CLEANstate"],
        },
        language="en",
        addressdetails=True,
    ).raw,
    axis=1,
)
```

Similarly, if you wanted to make a single row of the dictionaries first, you could do:

```py
df["full"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: {
        "city": row["CLEANtown"],
        "county": row["CLEANcounty"],
        "state": row["CLEANstate"],
    },
    axis=1,
)
df["easycode"] = df["full"].apply(
    lambda x: Ngeocode(
        x,
        language="en",
        addressdetails=True,
    ).raw
)
```

Comment: awesome - this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!